# What is this tank on the wheel of a Westland Wessex HAS31B?

Tags: feature-identification, westland-wessex

What is this tank on the wheel of a Westland Wessex HAS31B?

[image]
I'm talking about the white tank on the left of the picture. Photo taken in Darwin aviation museum, own work, public domain.

Comment: I know the grey cylinder attached to the wheel itself is part of an emergency flotation device - perhaps the two are related?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the compressed gas bottle (nitrogen or CO2) for the Wessex's emergency water floatation system. The dome on the right outside the tire is a cover for the actual float (sort of like a heavy duty version of a weather balloon). It operates like a Fire Extinguisher bottle, using an electrically fired explosive squib to penetrate a sealing disc and release the gas to inflate the float. It'll be fired automatically when water is sensed, so if you are forced down on water the floats pop out as the gear enters the water.

[image]

Comment: How do they stop it from firing when it rains a lot?  If pressure activated, if you fly in death valley a lot?

Comment: @SethRobertson, the difference in atmospheric pressure between sea level and the shore of the Dead Sea is equivalent to the difference in water pressure between the surface and 60 centimeters below the surface.

Comment: @Mark: that's my point.  It looks like the hull is just above knee level, off the ground (round to 1m) and looks like the wheel is about the full height of the ground clearance.  60cm is probably around the actual hull level.  How far does the helicopter have to sink before it activates?

Comment: Pretty sure it requires immersion in water so once armed it would discharge as soon as the water was above the tires. Older systems also sometimes were only manually fired.

Comment: An air-filled chamber with a downward pointing "drinking straw" entrance would keep rain out pretty well due to surface tension. However, enough water pressure (pressure above ambient air) would force water into the chamber to be detected. Is this how it works?

Comment: Not sure of the sensing mechanism itself. You could just use a float switch. If you root around for websites that make and sell these systems, you might find out exactly how they work.